# No notification of new email received on SGN4 lock screen

Tags: notifications, email, samsung-galaxy-note-4, lock-screen-widgets

Can anyone please advise on how to activate a function that will allow me to view lock screen notifications when an email is received just as I can with missed calls and sms messages etc.
The only way I become aware an email has been received is by noticing the addition of a status bar icon once the phone has been unlocked. 
If it helps I am currently using the stock email client and run with kitkat 4.4.4.
To date I have tried all I can to find this facility but to no avail. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you get the Lollipop OTA upgrade, your only option is to use a third-party lockscreen. Some good ones are:

- [L Lock screen by Lucky Coin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.luckycoin.lockscreen)
- [CM Locker by Cheetah Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cmcm.locker)

Comment: You may want to be careful about recommending Cheetah apps based on a new report out about Cheetah, and Google Play actions against them. See this: [https://www.xda-developers.com/google-bans-600-apps-play-store/](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-bans-600-apps-play-store/).